# How do supersampling works?

Tags: gpu, anti-aliasing

The definition that can be found in the web says:

```
"Splits single pixel into sub-pixels (...)"
```

and this is the part that I do not understand.

Typical pixel on screen is made of 3 sub-pixels.

What will happen if we turn ON the 4x supersampling?
Is each of those subpixels will be "divided" by 4 and algorithm will randomly pick up 4 samples?

Or this is about some kind of "software sub-pixels" that are about to be projected on to the monitor.

Comment: I believe it means that the image is rendered 4X larger than normal internally and then that is supersampled down to the actual desired resolution. This would provide 16 "subpixels" from which to choose the subsamples. See the [Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling).

Comment: Well, I have found a nice article about that mechanizm [LINK](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/78546-antialiasing-and-anisotropic-filtering-explained/3) however you are also right. Misunderstanding came from using same names for: "pixel's RGB subpixels" and "subpixel that is a result of pixel's "divide" in supersampling process". Thank you for inspiration.